# Please Help Javascript memory leak cycling data every second

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a memory leak with javascript. The following code gets data from the database and returns the value in the textbox. This data is cycled every second and produces a memory leak. Using developer tools, the xmlHTTP requests are seen building up on the browser. Is there any way to fix this error?

```js
  //the following code gets data from the database
  var startVal = 1; //the start value 
  var stopVal = 451; //the stop value
  var presentVal = startVal;

  var int = self.setInterval(function () {
    getData(presentVal)
  }, 1000); //clock cycles every second

  function getData(str) //used to get data from the database by calling getdata.php file
  {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    {
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

          var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

          var data = response.split("<>");
          var temperature = "";
          temperature = data[1];
          document.getElementById("temperatureVal").value = temperature; ///Temperature Value

          if (presentVal < stopVal) {
            presentVal++;
            response = "";
          } else {
            //int=window.clearInterval(int); //stop timer
            presentVal = startVal; //start Over
            response = "";
          }
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/getData.php?index=" + str, true); //calls the getdata.php file
      xmlhttp.send();

    }
  }
```

Comment: increase cycle time, 1s is too fast for ajax process, the browser is probably taking more than 1s on each request.

Comment: I changed the cycle time to 10s but it still builds up but after every 10s

Comment: use firebug or chrome debug and check out the time the server is taking on each request, you can see it on "network" in ms(miliseconds), post time here

Comment: For every cycle it builds up. Hence if you have the cycle time for 1s, and it cycles for 5 seconds. Every second a memory leak is observed. In developer tools, network, XHR, will display 5 memory leaks as follows: getData.php?index=1, getData.php?index=2, getData.php?index=3, getData.php?index=4, getData.php?index=5

Comment: when you say "the xmlHTTP requests are seen building up on the browser" what do you mean? You understand that the dev tools will show each request, and there will be a new request every time, right? Are you sure there's a memory leak here?

Comment: @user2093562 those values are normal, how about the ms each one toke?

Comment: Yes it keeps building up and will eventually use up all the RAM causing the browser to display an error message "your computer is low on memory". When you check the task manager, the browser memory usage keep increasing.

Comment: i just noticed youre using get asynchronous, try setting changing it to false    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/getData.php?index=" + str, FALSE);

Comment: when changed to false it still creates the error.

Comment: after you're finished with your xmlhttp object try deleting it. Also, does this happen if you don't have the dev tools open? I'm not certain but I think having them open means requests are saved / logged instead of being discarded immediately after they go out of scope.

Comment: yes that is exactly the problem. It stores the request after the request is made and does not delete it. I am taking the first row and displaying it in a textbox and after every second, it will display the next row. I tried to delete it but was not successful. It does not display anything when I try deleting.

Comment: you would have to delete it at the end of your onreadystatechange. delete it too quickly and you'll cancel the request. Or it would be simpler to just reuse the same object. This page may be helpful : http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/02/08/

Comment: thank you but I still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

At the start of `getData` you are creating a new variable `xmlhttp`, this creates a new and totally separate variable every time `getData` is called. To fix your problem, reuse the same `xmlhttp` variable instead of creating a new one (either use `window.xmlhttp` or define `var xmlhttp` at a higher function scope). (I previously said you could delete the object to clear memory but this apparently doesn't work.)

Call `new XMLHttpRequest()` just once, outside of getData, and you should be ok.

Comment: I tried using the delete xmlhttp; after my code in the if statement and placed the var xmlhttp outside the getData function but it still builds up memory.

Comment: edited my answer. delete should work but you can try invoking the XMLHttpRequest constructor just once.

Comment: I need to get data from the database and display it every second. Hence the XMLHtttpRequest calls every second

Comment: then use a pool of three or four XMLHttpRequests. You can still call `.open` and `.send` on an old request object, thereby recycling it.

Comment: I was doing some more testing and I found that every time an xmlhttp request is made, memory builds up in the browser. I need to display data every second and each off the requests will use memory. By chance you know of a solution or another way of doing this? thank you for all your time and suggestions.